# Send a message using discord.py without a function

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot and I am trying to find a way to send a message to the user/channel without the discord.py command since its updating all the time and waiting for a specific event that is not part of discord so I cant have it in the on_message function. how would I pass ctx to be able to send the message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to make a start command for the loop.

```
import time

@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    delay = 60
    await ctx.send("message")
    time.sleep(delay)
```